# How can I hide the text under the desktop icons?

Tags: nautilus, icons, customization, desktop-icons

I want to display the desktop icons without the text. I only have the Home and Trash icons on the desktop. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open gconf-editor, and go to apps>nautilus>preferences and change the desktop font to 0 (eg. change it from Sans 10 to Sans 0), then there's no text visible.

Comment: With this solution, technically it is still there, it is only reduced to an invisible font-size. Is there no solution where it is really removed?

Answer (score 1):

As of at least 14.04 the gconf schema of `apps > nautilus > preferences` no longer exists. The new, recommended, method is to use dconf to change the font size to 0.

The key is located under `org.gnome.nautilus.desktop` and called `font`. You can edit it with dconf editor (in the `dconf-tools` or `dconf-editor` packages). Or by using `gsettings` from the CLI:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font "Ubuntu 0"
```

To revert the changes make the key empty, either from the dconf-editor gui or with gsettings from the CLI:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font ""
```

The default value appears to be `Ubuntu 11`, even though the key is blank.